# Add cancel and save buttons in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to add save and cancel buttons in the action bar of my application when I am in an activity that allows inserting data to the user, in the same way as for example shows the Trello application: [image: example trello]

I need these buttons to be shown only in a specific activity, but not in the other activities of the application. I do not know how to implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Here setHomeAsUpIndicator is creating the dismiss btn and menu is creating the done btn.
hope this answers the query.*

> Set the toolbar

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_appbarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="snap"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_dismiss_24dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

> Set the actionbar dismiss btn

```
toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
ActionBar supportActionBar = getSupportActionBar();

if (supportActionBar != null) {
    supportActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    supportActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_dismiss_24dp);
```

> Set the functions inside your activity for menu

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_page, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_done:
            // done btn functionalities goes here
            break;
        case android.R.id.home:
            //dismiss btn functionality goes here
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

> Set the menu file(menu_page) inside res/menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="____your context____">


    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_done"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_done_24dp"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/done"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

Comment: : AAPT: error: attribute layout_scrollFlags (aka com.example.webkit:layout_scrollFlags) not found.

Answer (score 0):

you can custom your own toolbar and make theme in ManifestFile as no ActionBar 
and insert toolbar in every Activity as component